# Update swing JEditorPane from runnable class

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, runnable, settext

I am writing this java server program with Swing using intellij idea and I am trying to create a thread from my main class that will start a server and update a JEditorPane in another class. So far my code is a long the lines of.

```
public class ServerClass implements Runnable {

    private ClassWithLog statusLog = new ClassWithLog();

    public ServerClass() {
        startServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                startServer();
            }
         });
    }

    private void startServer() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
       .. Receive packet stuff here ..
       statusLog.updateData("Received...");

    }

}
```

Than I have my logging class which is a different form that contains code like so:

```
public class ClassWithLog {

    public ClassWithLog() {
       .. all the action listeners for swing..
    }

    public void updateData(String data) {
        logControl.setText(logControl.getText() + data);
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint in the updateData method and I see that data is getting my string I need but when logControl sets the text it is not showing in the form? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `repaint()`, calling after `logControl.setText()`.

Comment: @Braj I did try that, I also tried using revalidate() as well. No luck.

Comment: 1) Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) Does your text apper after `run()` method finished?

Comment: @trevercodes Is the EDT executing updateData(String)? (Can check by printing the result of SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread() in updateData)

Answer (score 1):

(Almost) all calls to methods on Swing classes, including components, should be made from the Event Dispatch Thread.

Change your updateData method:

```
public void updateData(String data) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        logControl.setText(logControl.getText() + data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To let Event Dispatcher Thread process your update wrap the call in

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()
```

It kind of stops current thread and pass control to EDT to reflect changes.